# How to call node.js library(XMLhttprequest,fetch, axiom) on hermes.net built in javasript editor

Tags: javascript, npm-install, npm-package

I have a problem to fix . i'am currently trying to call an api (Post + credential + body params) from a built in javascript editor that usualy help us to make interface for user and make control and conditions .

so the problem is that i can't load object from node.js that's needed to make proper api call like (XMLhttprequest,fetch, axiom) for exemple so the app compile the javascript on the server side and i can't acces to it ti install npm do you have any sugest about that problem .

Thanks .

I tried to solve the problem by many api call way even by curl call with javascript

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: global.XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest");
 let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let textToPost = `{
   "recipient" { "to": "212629043712"} 
   "body": { "text": "212629043712"} 
  }`;
  xmlHttp.open("POST", "https://rest.smsmode.com/sms/v1/messages", true);
  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  xmlHttp.send(textToPost);

Answer (score -1):

global.XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest");
let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
let textToPost = `{ "recipient" { "to": "212629043712"}  "body": { "text": "212629043712"}  }`;
xmlHttp.open("POST", "https://rest.smsmode.com/sms/v1/messages", true);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xmlHttp.send(textToPost);